# why Tags Come to google first page?

Tags: seo, tags

Sometimes when I search a query which is the target keyword for one of my blog posts, the tag page that contains a list of blog posts that have the are tagged appear in SERP instead of the blog post itself.

Why sometimes, Tags Come to google first page? and Will our content
post disappear(Fade)? for example My content was on the first link.But
suddenly deleted and The tag associated with it came to the front
page.

My question is two part:

1- my site is about repair shop and My search result yesterday about "Kia repair shop": [image: ![enter image description here]

2- My search result today about "Kia repair shop": [image: ![enter image description here]

Tags: [image: ![enter image description here]

Why did that? and How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tags come to the google first page"?  Are you saying that your WordPress tag page is sometimes ranking instead of article pages?     Your screen shots in arabic are confusing for an English language Q and A site.   It appears the text direction is switched.  Does that have something to do with your question?   Why did you include a screenshot from this site?   What does that have to do with your site?

Comment: He means tag pages that contain a list of blog posts come up for the query that is the target keyword for the post.

Comment: " Are you saying that your WordPress tag page is sometimes ranking instead of article pages? " oh yes. Exactly. you guess right. Please answer me. How can i resolve this problem.

Comment: Tags do some interesting jobs. They make a sparse graph to a dense graph. They make internal link and make a page with higher authority in comparison with post pages so can make better rank.